# Random vibration duration

Tags: android, random, vibration

I used this android code that when a user touch a screen, vibration is started and continued for 3000 ms. I don't want that always that user touch the screen, the duration of the vibration become the same as previous times(3000 ms). I want to use random that each time the vibration lasts for a random amount of time. How should I use random according to my code?

Please help me.

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
{    
   if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
   {    
      Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);    
      v.vibrate(3000);    
   }    
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Random` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html).

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

private int randRange(int min, int max) {
    return min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
}

public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(randRange(min, max)); // integer variables of your choice
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

See the documentation of [`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) to understand why I wrote the `randRange` method the way I did, if it confuses you.

Comment: Thanks. But your randRage function doesn't work for me. When I run the app and I touch the screen, it is closed by "forced to close" error.

Comment: My `randRange` function was missing a return type (`int`, now corrected), and a parenthesis. Other than that, it works fine. Have you already noticed and fixed these mistakes? If not, try now. If it still doesn't work, then remove the `randRange` call and see if the problem still appears, it could be something else.